# Ubuntu 32 bit tripple boot with 64 bit AND mac OS via Reffit

Tags: ubuntu, mac, 64-bit, multi-boot, 32-bit

I am on a Mac machine which is dual booted with Ubuntu (We have to keep the mac OS partition on the machine otherwise it refuses to work properly, it is however never used) however today when I went to put in the new RAM I desperately needed we found out that the Ubuntu I am running is only 32 bit, and this is an issue because I'm doing some fairly memory intensive stuff.

We use Refit currently to dual boot, could we just create a third partition, install 64 bit Ubuntu 10, move my files/settings across from the 32-bit OS I've been working on for several months then just remove the old 32-bit OS?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can do this.

Comment: I was just curious how painful people think this process will be.

Comment: Depends on your ability to problem solve.  How painful it is very subjective.